# How To Move A File Out Of The Inbox Folder When Using Airdrop Between iOS Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, airdrop

I am sending database file successfully between iOS devices with the following code:

```
-(void) doSendDatabase {
UIView *viewTemp = [[UIView alloc] init];
viewTemp.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300, 300);

NSString *currentDatabaseName;

// This is the full path and file name with ext
currentDatabaseName = [self.databases objectAtIndex:[[mainTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:currentDatabaseName];

UIActivityViewController * airDrop = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                         initWithActivityItems:@[url]
                                         applicationActivities:nil];    

airDrop.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;

[self presentViewController:airDrop
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];

[url release];
[airDrop release];
[viewTemp release];}
```

This code works and the database successfully gets sent from the sending iOS device to the receiving device.  However, the databases are stored in the Documents/Inbox folder (by design I suppose).  I simply want to move the received database files from the Inbox folder up one level into the Documents folder.  From what I'm reading I need to handle this in openURL in the App Delegate - but am not sure how to go about this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - here's what I did to resolve the problem.

(1) I created a handleInboxItems method in the App Delegate.

```
-(bool) handleInboxItems {
bool success = YES;
// Get the DBAccess object
DBAccess *dbAccess = [[DBAccess alloc] init];
// Get the Func object
Func *funcObject = [[Func alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *docDatabases;
// get a list of all database files in the Documents/Inbox folder ans store them in the inboxDatabases array
NSMutableArray *inboxDatabases = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *inboxDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Inbox"];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:inboxDirectory];
for (NSString *inboxFileAndPath in directoryEnumerator)
{
    //check to see if any of the files in the inbox folder end in the database extension - if so then save it in the inboxDatabases array
    if ([[inboxFileAndPath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@“dbext”])
    {
        [inboxDatabases addObject:[inboxDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:inboxFileAndPath]];
    }
}

// now go through the inboxDatabases array and copy them from the Documents/Inbox folder to the Documents folder

// loop through all inbox database and see if any of the database names already exist in Documents - if so then we need to tack on a sequential number
for (NSString *inboxDatabaseFileAndPath in inboxDatabases)
{
    NSString *inboxDatabaseName = [[inboxDatabaseFileAndPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    // Get the databases array from the DBAccess class (from the Documents folder)  - need to get each time since we are moving files in there
    docDatabases = [dbAccess getAllDatabases];

    // does the inbox database already exist in the documents folder?
    NSUInteger arrayIndex = [docDatabases indexOfObject:[funcObject databaseNameToFullPathName:allTrim(inboxDatabaseName)]];

    int i = 0;
    while (arrayIndex != NSNotFound)
    {
        ++i;
        NSString *tempDatabaseName = [NSString stringWithFormat:[inboxDatabaseName stringByAppendingString:@" %d"],i];

        // see if the database (with sequential number) already exists
        arrayIndex = [docDatabases indexOfObject:[funcObject databaseNameToFullPathName:allTrim(tempDatabaseName)]];
        if (arrayIndex == NSNotFound)
        {
            // it does not exist, we can use this name
            inboxDatabaseName = tempDatabaseName;
        }
    }
    // give it full path and extension
    NSString *docDatabaseFileAndPathToWrite = [funcObject databaseNameToFullPathName:allTrim(inboxDatabaseName)];
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:inboxDatabaseFileAndPath toPath:docDatabaseFileAndPathToWrite error:&error];
    if (success)
    {
        // delete the inbox database file
        success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:inboxDatabaseFileAndPath error:&error];
        if (!success)
        {
            NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to delete inbox database:'%@'.",[error localizedDescription]);
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to copy inbox database to documents folder:'%@'.",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

[dbAccess release];
[funcObject release];
[inboxDatabases release];

return success;}
```

(2) Added a call to this new method in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the App Delegate just in case there is anything stuck in the inbox upon startup.

(3) I added the openURL method to the App Delegate in order to call handleInboxItems.  After done, I send a notification so that I can refresh my database list.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{
bool success = [self handleInboxItems];

if (success)
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIF_DATABASE_AIRDROPPED object:self];

return success;}
```

That's it - works as I need it to.